# Google's SupportMapFragment type cast exception with v4 Fragment

Tags: android, androidx

**Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'**

I created fresh project for google map integration, there also (first tried in ongoing project) the same type cast exception in editor. Have seen many other similar question, but those were for type cast exception for android.app.Fragment with SupportMapFragment and even their accepted answer were to use android.support.v4.app.Fragment with SupportMapFragment to resolve error, but in my case, the same is giving me an error. (So this might seem duplicate but contrary it's not.). Please suggest solution for this.

Comment: yes because every SupportMapFragment is a Fragment but not every Fragment is not a SupportMapFragment.

Comment: That's why we cast, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little deep diving, found that in my case, `SupportMapFragment` extends `Fragment` which belonged to *Jetpack's* `androidx` package

and

my `AppCompatActivity` having `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(id)` methods returning a `Fragment`, all these belonged to traditional `android` package.

`androidx` package is a completely different than but parallel to`android` package, as per [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

> AndroidX maps the original support library API packages into the
>   androidx namespace. Only the package and Maven artifact names changed;
>   class, method, and field names did not change.

So, I was getting type-cast-exception as in below statement:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Exception:

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to
>   'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'

In order to resolve this issue, I need to migrate my existing project to `androidx`.